# Filter Multiple connections List (no-code solution)

Tags: 2007, web-part, list, filter

I have a mission to create a filter for any field of my list, there are many. 
The connection is just made in the first filter, I cannot connect more than once...

I've searched for code which would allow multiple connections, BUT the access is too limited in my company, I cannot open Visual Studio, even SharePoint Designer 2007... it's unfair work without tools but be pressed to achieve the same results.

So, have you some tip/suggestion for me ? 
Some code in jQuery or something like that, I could insert in a CEWP ?

(I'm using Sharepoint 2007)

Many Thanks

Susantt

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at these solutions:

- http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2011/01/26/sharepoint-list-views-ndashquick-amp-easy-jquery-filter.aspx
- http://www.bentedder.com/create-a-jquery-sharepoint-instant-searchfilter/
- http://www.cyclingjames.com/sharepoint/filter-the-current-sharepoint-list-view-as-you-type/
- http://modery.net/providing-filter-dropdowns-for-a-sharepoint-listlibrary-with-jquery/
- http://www.sharepointbinder.com/1/post/2012/2/filters.html

Comment: Hi C. Marius, I will take a look at these links and write back.. thanks in advance for the research :)